# Can't declare public String (illegal start of expression)

Tags: java, regex

I'm making a simple text based rpg. I am getting this error: `"illegal start of expression"`. when I remove the public modifier from String enemy, it fixes the illegal start of expression error, but creates two `"cannot find symbol"` errors.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class rpggame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(;;)//Character Creation
    {       
            //All the code here is irrelevant to my problem, removed for space
    }
        Enemy rat = new Enemy(5, 5, 5, 1);
        Enemy slime = new Enemy(5, 5, 5, 1);
        Enemy bat = new Enemy(5, 5, 5, 1);
        Enemy bunny = new Enemy(5, 5, 5, 1);

        System.out.println("Time to battle! What do you want to fight?\nA. Rat\nB. Slime\n C. Bat\n D.Bunny");
            String enemyChoice = input.next();
            public String enemy; //Error here
            enemy = null;

            switch(enemyChoice)
            {
                case "a":
                case "A":
                    enemy = "Rat";
                break;
                case "b":
                case "B":
                    enemy = "Slime";
                break;
                case "c":
                case "C":
                    enemy = "Bat";
                break;
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    enemy = "Bunny";
                break;
            }
            battle(); //When I remove the public modifier from enemy, I get "cannot find symbol" here.



}//end of main method



    public static class Enemy
        {
            public static int enemyDamage;
            public static int enemySpeed;
            public static int enemyDefense;
            public static int enemyLevel;

            Enemy(int Da,int Sp,int De,int Lv)
            {
                enemyDamage=Da;
                enemySpeed=Sp;
                enemyDefense=De;
                enemyLevel=Lv;
            }

            public void battle() {
                    System.out.println("You have encountered " + rpggame.enemy + " Level" + enemyLevel); //When I remove the public modifier from enemy, I get "cannot find symbol" here.
                }

        }}//Closing brace for rpggame
```

Comment: What do you think declaring a local variable as public should do?

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers (`public`, `private`, and `protected`) can be applied to fields (and methods, and classes). They cannot be applied to local variables, as it makes no sense.

Local variables can be accessed from anywhere after their declaration, in block they are declared in, except for inside anonymous classes and lambda expressions (which have special rules).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know what to do with the public keyword. You are declaring a local variable so a visibility keyword is useless. You should also initialize it to null or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main
```

is a function, not a class.
You must not use indicator for variables inside a function. 
If you use 'public' for a class member, you can specify its visibility from outside.
However, a scope of a variable inside a function is inside a function. It is not visible from outside.

battle() needs an indicater (of an instance). E.g.,

```
rat.battle();
```

Last, rpggame class does not have a field called 'enemy.' 
You may need a field inside a rpggame class. E.g.,

```
public class rpggame {
private Enemy enemy;
public static void main(String[] args) {
```